# tkinter back ground doesnt change

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a little game for a college project, I have created a fucntion that chagnes the screen, this currently works, however when i call the show screen function so the background changes and the game function is called, tkinter stops working, it runs the first 3 functions then ruins the 4th however nothing happens, the print statements in the start_game() function appear in the command line however, 3 statements above seem to have done nothing and my tkinter widget freezes. and stays on the current screen, not being updated.

```
def showGameSurvival():
   clearScreen()
   changeBackground("Survival")
   createBackButton(showMain, 1003, 492)
   start_game()
```

I am unsure how i get arround this as i dont quite know the error itself as there are no error messages, do i need threading or what?
thankyou very much, Tom.

```
def changeBackground(image):
    filename = PhotoImage(file = filePath + image + ".png")
    background_label = Label(root, image=filename)
    background_label.image = filename
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

def clearScreen():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
```

code regarding recent comment:

```
def showGameSurvival():
    clearScreen()
    changeBackground("Survival")
    createBackButton(showMain, 1003, 492)
    print('1')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('2')
```

Comment: Please provide Trackback and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I noticed in your function `changeBackground(image):` you are using the word `image` as an argument and it is also a built in tkinter function. You might want to change the argument name to something like `img` to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: Do you have your code posted on github? There is a good reason why we ask for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In writing the MCVE you often figure out what is going wrong with your program and solve your own problem. If you are still unable to solve with writing the MCVE it can then be posted here to give us some usable code to work with and work out your problem.

Comment: I think this might explain it better, if it doesnt ill drop it on git hub. so when the function is called 1 is printed then 5 seconds goes past then 2 is printed then the tkinter actions above it happen. But i want the actions to happen then then 5 seconds to be waited, is that possible?
Code added to end of question

Comment: Don't Use sleep in tkinter. Instead use the `.after()` method. I will post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in regards to your latest comment. We can use the `after()` method to perform the wait time you are attempting to accomplish.

Keep in mind if you use `.sleep()` the entire application will sleep and not just the function you are using.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def showGameSurvival():
    #do stuff
    print('1')
    #do other stuff
    root.after(5000, lambda: print('2')) # 1000 for every full second
    #do more stuff

showGameSurvival()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this! I have never heard of .after before and using lambda! this has worked for me and helped me so much! Thankyou!!

Comment: lambda is used to create anonymous functions you can get more  information [HERE](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk). Note: The use of `.after()` is how tkinter manages wait time. So anytime (for the most part) you would want to use sleep just use after instead. And you are welcome :)

Comment: Hey, sorry another similar thing just popped up, so when show survival games is called there is a section in here which places a label: the code is as follows:         lbl = Label(fg=lbBlue, font=SMALL_BUTTON_FONT)
        lbl['text'] = 'level: ' + str(game.level)
        lbl.place(x=35, y=15)
and nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: @TomDavis That should be asked in another question but from looking at your line of code you are missing the window identifier. `lbl = (fg=lbBlue` should be something like `lbl = (root, fg = lbBlue` where root is whatever window or frame you are placing it in.